# How can I listen to an attribute change in Ractive

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

If I have an object 
how can I have something that tracks the changes in hello. the otherobject.value will continuously change and I want to get updates about this changes.

I want to be able to have a function such as:

function helloUpdated(newValueOrWhatever){
}

which will be fired everytime the value of the 'hello' attribute is changed by the otherobject.value. However I do not want to directly interact with otherobject or otherobject.value.

Answer (score 4):

Check out 
http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-observe

You can observe objects that is changed by ractive